# Character set ISO-8859-1 displaying improperly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My default character encoding is Western (ISO latin 1, ISO-8859-1).  I am using this code to change the character set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

My website only displays properly when I click on "Text Encoding" then "Western (ISO latin 1)" in the Safari view menu.  Even when set on default (Safari text encoding menu), it still doesn't display properly (weird black-diamond question marks).  I am using ruby on rails, if that might be an issue with the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following to your `application_controller` :

```
before_filter :headers_iso

def headers_iso
  headers["content-type"]= "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
end
```

Comment: I have a complete write-up here http://www.dixis.com/?p=48 of the troubles i had to go trough to get it to work for me. I was hoping that that single change was enough. Maybe you should read it. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a safari problem.
In PHP you can solve this by adding :

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'); ?>
```

BEFORE any text output or echo().

I maintain a site witch is done like this :

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML ...
```

Comment: Why do you explain about php, when the question is about ruby-on-rails?